# Thread-based parallelism for native code in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a hybrid C++/Python project where all the heavy lifting is done in C++ and Python serves as a glue layer. Python part looks something like this:

```py
results = []
for args in my_args_range:
    results.append(my_cpp_function_wrapped_with_pybind11(args))
...  # process results
```

I would like to parallelize this loop. I understand that Python has GIL, so thread-based parallelism would do no good for pure Python code, and this is why `multiprocessing` is the default approach to parallelism in Python. But as I see it there is no reason why hermetic C++ functions can't be executed in parallel within the same process.

Is there a (simple) way to have a thread-based parallelism in this case?

Comment: If the C/C++ release the GIL, then `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` may work. For example, `cffi` extension release GIL when C functions are called.

Comment: Now that I think about it, releasing GIL on C++ side makes a lot of sense since converting function arguments and return value to/from Python should probably happen under GIL as well. I found that pybind11 provides `py::gil_scoped_release` class. This sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks!